# Proving that the permutation 312 is not stack-sortable

Tags: discrete-mathematics, permutations, sorting

[image: push operation]

[image: pop operation]

We say that a permutation $σ ∈ S_n $ is sortable through a stack if there is a sequence of (PUSH) and (POP) operations such that the initial state:

[image: permutation]

can be transformed into the final state:

[image: after sorting]

I’m supposed to prove that the permutation 312 is not stack sortable. Other than writing out all the different combinations of possible operations, I’m not sure how to show this.

Comment: Well, the first move must be a push since there's nothing on the stack to pop.  Which number must be the first number that you pop?

Comment: I need to push the 2 first. 3 needs to be popped first. Obviously, the problem comes with getting the 2 popped before the 1.